# как запустить 2 сайта на разных ip (apache)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache, ip, apache2

Есть дедик. К нему привязано 2 ip адреса. Также есть сервер apache. Хотелось бы запустить 2 сайта на разных ip.
Каким образом это можно сделать?
Разные ip адреса мне нужны для будущей привязки двух разных доменов.

Comment: а) разные домены можно и на один адрес привязать. б) это основы настройки веб-сервера. Попробуйте почитать документацию.

Comment: Угу, у `nginx` - это `server_name`.